# Code not running in hackerrank even though it is running in VS Code

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to solve a list-comprehension problem on hackerrank: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/list-comprehensions/problem?isFullScreen=true. However, when I run the code in vsCode it works but it does not run when I submit it to hackerrank.

I tried adding parenthesis and brackets.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = int(input())
    y = int(input())
    z = int(input())
    n = int(input())
    print [[i,j,k] for i in range(x+1) for j in range(y+1) for k in range(z+1) if ((i+j+k) != n)]
```

Comment: Well, you'll definitely need parens in the print if you're using Python 3. The code you've provided here should fail anywhere you try to run it with Python 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to put parentheses around the print statement. Try changing the last line to:

```
print([[i,j,k] for i in range(x+1) for j in range(y+1) for k in range(z+1) if ((i+j+k) != n)])
```